# Image saved always empty with Storage::put in Laravel

Tags: php, image, laravel, base64, laravel-storage

I am trying to save a file using Storage::put but it always saves an empty image file and I don't understand why.The file I try to save is base64 encoded.

Here is my code:

```
  $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $file);
  $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
  $decodedFile = base64_decode($image);


  // Image Size
  $size = strlen($decodedFile);

  // Image Mime Type
  $f = finfo_open();
    $mimeType = finfo_buffer($f, $decodedFile, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  finfo_close($f);

  // Extension
  $extension = explode('.', $filename)[1];
  $error = null;
  $test = $public;

  // Save file locally
  Storage::put('tmp/temporary', $decodedFile);

  $object = new UploadedFile($url, $filename, $mimeType, $size, $error, $test);
```

This is what I get as result, size is always 0

```
UploadedFile {#307 ▼
-test: false
-originalName: "wassho-omni-shoreham-hotel-marquee-lounge.jpg"
-mimeType: "image/png"
-size: 185463
-error: 0
path: "na_source/public/storage/tmp"
filename: "temporary"
basename: "temporary"
pathname: "na_source/public/storage/tmp/temporary"
extension: ""
realPath: "na_source/storage/app/public/tmp/temporary"
aTime: 2017-10-19 21:59:45
mTime: 2017-10-19 21:03:12
cTime: 2017-10-19 21:59:07
inode: 11166493
size: 0
perms: 0100644
owner: 1000
group: 1000
type: "file"
writable: true
readable: true
executable: false
file: true
dir: false
link: false
}
```

Someone knows what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: what is `$file`? Content of the file?

Comment: $file is the base64 encoded file content

Comment: Kinda struggeling with storage myself right now, so just shouting my thoughts: $size > 0 I guess?, $public = false?? Perhaps use an extension, any, so that it does not look like a path?

Comment: Are `Storage::put` and `UploadedFile` pointing to the same file?

Comment: @ljubadr yes, they do, I save the file temporarily and then use the url path in the UploadedFile object, is that not something I can do here?

Comment: @Jeffrey I actually found a solution that works for me, I replaced Storage::put($url, $decodedFile); with the native PHP file_put_contents($url, $decodedFile); function, and voila it works with above code together, although I do not understand why it does not work with Storage::put() ...., might be a path issue when I use Storage::put() ?

Comment: hard to say without running the whole example... but I'm glad you found a solution...

Comment: @ljubadr yes, thanks for having a look! I will mark it as solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was not completely clear to me why, but exchanging Storage::put function with file_put_contents($url, $decodedFile); function solved the issue, and it saved the file without a hitch using above code.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is not correct. because its hard coded for PNG images.

```
$image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $file);
```

Instead of that you can use below line.

```
$tempImage = explode(",",$file);
$image_data = base64_decode($tempImage[1]);

$file_name = "getYourFileName.PNG";
//After decoding from base64. you can save it using 

File::put('tmp/temporary/' . $file_name , $image_data);
```