# Image upload on laravel doesn't work online : Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The project works fine on my localhost but has issues on a live shared server.

1. I have tried adding this code to my index.php

```
// set the public path to this directory
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

2. I have tried adding this code in a new sym.php file in my public folder

```
<?php 

$targetFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage/app/public';
$linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/public/storage';
symlink($targetFolder,$linkFolder);
echo 'Symlink process successfully completed';


?>
```

3. I have tried adding this on my web.php and then running site/linkstorage

```
Route::get('/linkstorage', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

None of these solutions works

here is a snippet of my Controllers code:

```
    public function storeBrand(Request $request){
            $this->validate($request, ['brand_name'=> 'required',
                'brand_url'=> 'required',
                'brand_image'=>'image|nullable|max:1999']);
    
    
    
            if($request->hasFile('brand_image')){
                //1 : get filename with ext
                $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('brand_image')->getClientOriginalName();
    
                //2 : get just file name
                $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    
                //3 : get just extension
                $extension = $request->file('brand_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    
                //4 : file name to store
    
    
                $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
    
                //upload image
    
                $path =$request->file('brand_image')->storeAs('public/BrandImages', $fileNameToStore);
    
            }
    
            else{  
    
                $fileNameToStore ='noimage.jpg';
    
            }
    
            $brand=new Brand();
            $brand->brand_name =$request->input('brand_name');
            $brand->brand_url =$request->input('brand_url');
            
    
            $brand->brand_image =$fileNameToStore;
    
            $brand->save();
    
            return redirect('/create_brand')->with('status', 'The '.$brand->brand_name.' Brand has been saved successfully. Create another one.');
```

**Note**

When an image is uploaded the path can be traced, but the image is not found, returns an empty image.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image saved always empty with Storage::put in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839581/image-saved-always-empty-with-storageput-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution:

I Wrote down this code in my web.php route file:

`Route::get('/linkstorage', function () { $targetFolder = base_path().'/storage/app/public'; $linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage'; symlink($targetFolder, $linkFolder); });`

After that I navigated to my url/linkstorage
It worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code in your controller, it seems correct. Perhaps the error is within your form in the Blade file associated with this method. Based on experience I tend to forget to write this and this could probably sort out your error.

Write this on the form tag.

```
<form action="{{ insert the route here }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   // insert form input fields here...
</form>
```